# Javascript views in RoR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

This mostly theoretical question on good practices and I am interested in opinions of fellow developers.

I have been working on an application that uses ajax to fetch, save or update mostly anything. While saving and fetching was not a problem, updating page content according to request result was.

Well at least until I have started utilizing javascript views.

Now, all I do is create a view for resource that is .js.erb and define what is to happen when view is called (using :remote => true). A dream come true.

However, since all good things must come with few gotchas there has to be something with this approach that will eventually come to haunt me. I just don't see it yet.

So, opinions... am I about to get bitten?

Comment: I'd recommend that you get bitten first. There may be a million things that could get you, yet you can't know before you do anything. It would be better if you ask about a real problem here.

Comment: Thank you, but I really don't have any real problems ATM. However, I do care about utilizing best practices as much as I can, and while this works perfectly, I might just be too pessimistic about the magic of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main rule that will keep you out of trouble in my opinion is:

- Turn off javascript in your browser, does your application still function? can you get around and perform the same actions? - You should be able to. This comes from the concept of "progressive enhancement" and IMHO is how javascript/ajax should be done, period.

Some additional points:

If your javascript views and "normal" views aren't using the the exact same template (partial) to draw things to the page, this will bite you. Having 2 places to maintain representations of something is a major pain. So make sure they are one in the same.

If your application is very javascript heavy and you require it enabled to function, you may consider thinking of the project in terms of an API-first development. Design and implement a feature complete RESTful JSON API that lets you perform all actions you need to, then build your UI on top of that. Side effect: now you have an API to give to your customers, and its the same one you use internally to drive your interface, simplifying and unifying development and maintenance.

I hope this helps set you off in a good direction!

Comment: API First development idea is fantastic. I have to remember it for one the future projects. *Back to the topic.* Normal views, if they exist are html (even remote ones) and are handled by a function in application.js. Only create and update action views are executable javascript which are used to update content on index action.

Comment: For those content pieces on the index action, draw them using partials, then re-use the same partials in the AJAX update for the edit/update result. Then you only have 1 'code representation', and your all set. Sorry if you understood that and I'm just being redundant :)